# Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{ R}$ be such that $f' (x)$ exists

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{ R}$ be such that $f' (x)$ exists for all non zero $x$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} f' (x) = 0$.

Then

(i) $f$ is continuous but not differentiable at $0$.

(ii) $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f' (0) = 0.$

(iii) $f$ has either a local maximum or a local minimum at $0$.

(iv) None of the above.

I am totally clueless. Thank you for help and discussion.

Comment: Cute question. ${}{}{}$

Comment: $f(x)=0$ for $x\ne0$, $f(0)=1$ could be a starting point.

Comment: Guess the behaviour of $f$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In my answer I suppose that $f$ is continuous at $0$**

Let $x>0$ then by the mean value theorem there's $\xi_x\in(0,x)$ s.t.
$$f(x)-f(0)=xf'(\xi_x)$$
so by passing to the limit $x\to0$ so $\xi_x\to 0$ and since $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)$ exists  we have
$$\lim_{x\to0}f'(\xi_x)=0=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(0)$$
hence $f'(0)=0$.

**Added** In the case where $f$ isn't continuous at $0$ you can see the answer of *cooper.hat* for a counterexample.

Comment: When you apply the Mean Value Theorem, you're assuming $f$ is continuous on $[0,x]$. But the problem, sadly, didn't assume $f$ was continuous at $0$. It seems (iv) is the only correct answer. But I'd like to believe they wanted students to know this argument :)

Comment: Yes I assumed that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Clearly the point of such problems is not to make any unwarranted assumptions. :)

Comment: I agree with you but if you look at the items $(i)$ and $(ii)$ you feel that at least implicitly  the lack of continuity assumption and otherwise the answer will be trivial, isn't it?

Comment: @copper.hat Ok i'll add this assumption and at least on looking at my answer and yours we can see the importance of this assumption or its lacking to the final result.

Comment: @copper.hat I edit my answer  and thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x >0 \\ 0 & x = 0 \\ -1 & x<0 \end{cases}$.

Then $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$ (and hence not differentiable).

$f$ has neither a local maximum or minimum at $x=0$.

Hence the answer is (iv) None of the above.

Comment: You're correct and in my work I supposed the further assumption that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

**IF** $f$ is continuous at $0$, it is easy to prove it is also differentiable.

Let $x \neq 0$. Then, by the MVT, there exists some $c_x$ between $0$ and $x$ so that

$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(c_x) $$

Now

$$\lim_{x \to 0}f'(x)=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to 0}f'(c_x)=0 \Rightarrow \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=0 \,.$$

This shows that $(i)$ is False.

(iii) $f(x)=x^3$.